# How to take multiple images and still keep the quality on Android java using ImageReader?

Tags: java, android, image, bitmap, take

I am trying to take multiple images on Android java using ImageReader. It's working fine if the user only takes a single image. But if they take multiple images at the same time (click the button continuously for a short duration) the images will be pixelated and unable to use.

Below you can see the result.
If I took a single image

[single image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cACS2.jpg)

If I took multiple images

[multiple images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TbmZ8.jpg)

I'm using bitmate to take the image.

```
byte[] imageData = ImageUtils.NV21toJPEG(ImageUtils.YUV420toNV21(image), image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), 100);
Bitmap bitmapImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageData, 0, imageData.length, null);
```

transform the bitmap into image

```
public static File bitmapToFile(Bitmap bitmap, String fileNameToSave, Context context) {
    File file = null;
    try {
        file = new File(context.getExternalCacheDir() + File.separator + fileNameToSave);
        file.createNewFile();

        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bos);
        byte[] bitmapdata = bos.toByteArray();

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        fos.write(bitmapdata);
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
        return file;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return file; // it will return null
    }
```

The reason I can think of is. When the user click the button multiple time, the image couldn't finish the process fast enough so the image got pixelated. I try to add a sleeping thread and also disable the button, but it takes so long for the image to finish the process (if I set it below 2.5s ~ 2500ms the image will still be pixelated)

```
try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
```

Can someone advise me what I should do with this situation? is it the way I generate the image or Somehow I can check if the Image is perfectly generated and then allow the user to take the image again. I believe it should have been possible for the user to take multiple images in a short time.

Comment: It is unclear to me what you consider to be 'taking an image'. I see no such. Also i see no button. I see no bitmate either.

Comment: `file.createNewFile();` Remove that statement. Do away with bos as you can directly compress to fos.

Comment: I would not call that pixelated.

Comment: sorry for the confusion. what I mean is I want to take a screenshot from the camera and If I click the button too many times. The Image will look like picture 2. Maybe not pixelated but wrong.

Comment: Why didnt you adapt your code? Or react on it?

Comment: @blackapps I'm sorry, I'm quite new to using StackOverflow. May I ask what you mean adapt my code? Should I post other related codes also?

Comment: So with `Remove that statement` you dont know what to do?

Comment: oh, you are right and I have removed the line file.createNewFile() replace it with other code and this time I create the file from the byte[] itself not from byte[] -> bitmap -> file anymore. The images are improved but sometimes pixel errors still occur. Often the first image is when I click the taking image button too many times.

Comment: You have not changed the code here.